# How to run an terminal command from XcodeTest setup()?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I want to run a shell/bash command on my computer from an iOS XCTest `setup()` method to restart a local test server.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could use `Process` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) for that

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: is available on macOS only

Comment: Ok, I see. A unit test should not be using a server but have you looked if you could run a script as a part of the XCode scheme for your tests?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It's an integration test obviously. And we would love to reset the server for ech test, thus it must run in `setup()`.

Comment: Maybe add a restart API, and call it from synchronous web task